# Unable to get the all rows from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing small app called Stock Manager. I want to return all the row details into the listview. But I am receiving only last row details only.

Check this Database file DataBaseHandler.java

```
package com.example.stockmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private SQLiteDatabase sql=null;
    private static String CREATE_TABLE="";

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, Util.DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +Util.STOCK_TABLE + "("
                +Util.USER_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +Util.CURRENT_STOCK +" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +Util.DATE +" TEXT NOT NULL, "
                +Util.TIME +" TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Log.i("Authentication", ""+CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +Util.STOCK_TABLE);

    }

    public void insertDetails(Model m)
    {
        sql=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cn=new ContentValues();

        cn.put(Util.CURRENT_STOCK, m.getCurrentStock().toString());
        cn.put(Util.DATE, m.getDate().toString());
        cn.put(Util.TIME, m.getTime().toString());
        long insertId=sql.insert(Util.STOCK_TABLE, null, cn);
        Log.i("new raw inserted", ""+insertId);
    }

    public List<Model> getAllDetails()
    {
        List<Model> show=new ArrayList<Model>(); 
        sql=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=null;
        /*String query="SELECT * FROM " +Util.STOCK_TABLE+" ORDER BY "+Util.USER_ID+" ASC";
        cursor=sql.rawQuery(query, null);*/
        cursor=sql.query(Util.STOCK_TABLE, new String[] {Util.CURRENT_STOCK,Util.DATE,Util.TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Model m=new Model();
            m.setCurrentStock(cursor.getString(0));
            m.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            m.setTime(cursor.getString(2));

            show.add(m);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        sql.close();
        return show;
    }

     public String getLastStock()
     {
         sql=this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor;
            String q="SELECT "+Util.CURRENT_STOCK+" FROM "+Util.STOCK_TABLE+" ORDER BY " +Util.USER_ID+" DESC LIMIT 1";
            cursor=sql.rawQuery(q, null);
            String stock = null;
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                stock=cursor.getString(0);

        return stock;

     }
}
```

Check this java file History.java

```
package com.example.stockmanager;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class History extends Activity {

    private ListView lst;
    private Adaptar aa;
    private ArrayList<String> array_stock;
    private ArrayList<String> array_date;
    private ArrayList<String> array_time;
    private DataBaseHandler data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        data=new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        try
        {
        List<Model> ls=data.getAllDetails();

        array_stock = new ArrayList<String>(ls.size());
        array_date = new ArrayList<String>(ls.size());
        array_time = new ArrayList<String>(ls.size());

        Log.i("Size", ""+array_stock);

        for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++)
        {
            Model m=ls.get(i);
            String stock=m.getCurrentStock();
            String date=m.getDate();
            String time=m.getTime();


            Log.i("Stock", ""+stock);
            Log.i("date", ""+date);
            Log.i("time", ""+time);


            array_stock.add(stock);
            array_date.add(date);
            array_time.add(time);


        }

        aa=new Adaptar(this,ls);
        lst.setAdapter(aa);

        /*lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View rowView, int positon,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), ""+positon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                removeListItem(rowView,positon);
            }
        });*/

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /*protected void removeListItem(View rowView, final int positon) {

          final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(History.this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
          rowView.startAnimation(animation);
          Handler handle = new Handler();
          handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
              public void run() {
                  array_stock.remove(positon);
                  array_date.remove(positon);
                  array_time.remove(positon);

                  aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  animation.cancel();
              }
          },1000);

      }
*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.history, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check this adaptar class Adaptar.java

```
package com.example.stockmanager;

import java.util.List;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adaptar extends ArrayAdapter<Model> implements ListAdapter{

    private List<Model> lsadd;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;

    public Adaptar(History history, List<Model> ls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(history, R.layout.row, ls);
        this.lsadd=ls;
        inflator=history.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        protected TextView stock;
        protected TextView date;
        protected TextView time;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewholder=null;
        final int temposition= arg0;
        if(arg1==null)
        {
            arg1=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            viewholder=new ViewHolder();
            viewholder.stock=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            viewholder.date=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.t3);
            viewholder.time=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.t4);


            arg1.setTag(viewholder);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.t2, viewholder.stock);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.t3, viewholder.date);
            arg1.setTag(R.id.t4, viewholder.time);

            }
        else
        {
            viewholder=(ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        }


        viewholder.stock.setText(lsadd.get(temposition).getCurrentStock());
        viewholder.date.setText(lsadd.get(temposition).getDate());
        viewholder.time.setText(lsadd.get(temposition).getTime());
        return arg1;
        }

}
```

Logcat

```
03-23 11:15:43.080: I/Checking(1167): com.example.stockmanager.Model@b2da59b0
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Checking(1167): com.example.stockmanager.Model@b2d8fe48
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Checking(1167): com.example.stockmanager.Model@b2da7e20
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Checking(1167): com.example.stockmanager.Model@b2d87cf8
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Size(1167): []
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Stock(1167): 106
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/date(1167): 23-3-2015
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/time(1167): 11:12:13
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Stock(1167): 106
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/date(1167): 23-3-2015
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/time(1167): 11:12:13
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Stock(1167): 106
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/date(1167): 23-3-2015
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/time(1167): 11:12:13
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/Stock(1167): 106
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/date(1167): 23-3-2015
03-23 11:15:43.090: I/time(1167): 11:12:13
```

My database

```
user_id current_stock    date          time
1           50         24-3-2015      1:58:22
2           100        24-3-2015      1:58:26
3           150        24-3-2015      1:58:29
4           200        24-3-2015      1:58:36
5           195        24-3-2015      1:58:41
6           245        24-3-2015      1:58:49
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter you don't override method getCount as this :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lsadd.size();
}
```

And remove these lines:

```
    arg1.setTag(R.id.t2, viewholder.stock);
    arg1.setTag(R.id.t3, viewholder.date);
    arg1.setTag(R.id.t4, viewholder.time);
```

Comment: sorry this didn't helped me. @Laurenty

Comment: @user3778089, I update my answer, please remove lines as explained

Comment: still facing same problem. @Laurently

Comment: help me ... i didn't find any relevant solution for that. @Laurenty

Comment: @user3778089, add logs get get size of list, for instance at the end of method getAllDetails , in the constructor of Adaptar, ...

Comment: I have edited the post with the logcat. Check the log what actually i am receiving

Comment: check the log i am receiving same value again an again. for loop is working according to the size of array that what we receive from the getAllDetials() method. But the storing same value into the database.

Comment: @user3778089, I not understand your last comment and your logs, sorry

Comment: i mean to say, the logcat i have posted is returning only the last row from the database. Plz look the logcat. It doesn't return all the row value. It just returns only last row value. @LaurentY

Comment: @user3778089 If I understand, you not receive all rows from database. Are you sure others rows are present ? Have you dump database to double check ?

Comment: Yup all rows are present in database. But it returns only last row. @LaurentY

Comment: check the post again. I have posted database. @LaurentY

Answer (score 0):

try this example in your get allDetails method :

`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
      res.moveToFirst();
      while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
      array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
      res.moveToNext();
      }`

Comment: sorry this didn't helped me. @Hamza

Comment: in this code i tried to store all rows in an array list, but it works for me